# JAXB - Creating namespace attribute at child element level

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

JAXB by default seems to create namespace attributes (xmlns) at Root element level.  Is there a way to make namespace at Child element level ?

```html
-- XML output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:department xmlns:ns2="emp.test" xmlns:ns3="dep.test">
    <id>111</id>
    <ns2:employees>
        <name>Name-0</name>
    </ns2:employees>
</ns3:department>

-- Desired XML output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<department xmlns="dep.test">
    <id>111</id>
    <employees xmlns="emp.test">
        <name>Name-0</name>
    </employees>
</department>
```

Comment: No, and why do you care? JAXB way is much more efficient if namespace is used more than once.

Comment: Also note that the two are not the same. In your desired output, the `id` element is in namespace `dep.test`. In the JAXB output, the `id` element is without namespace. Similar for the `name` element.

Comment: Namespaces are meant to prefix all the elements the belong to it. In your case you declared `ns3` to be the prefix that denotes `dep.test` namespace. Why do you want to alter that behavior?